# Angularjs, express and nodejs bug with view rendering

Tags: node.js, angular, express, routes, public

I'm new in Angularjs and i'm trying to create a basic one page app using ngRoute. But i have a problem. I wan't my user to get the index.html file everytime. But if the url is /page1 my server is returning the page1 so index.html isn't loading. I tryed to fix it by doing like that :

Angular file :

```
 test.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : '/page1',
            controller  : 'trapController'
        })
        .when('/test', {
            templateUrl : '/page2',
            controller  : 'trapController'
        });
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

Node.js file :

```
require('dotenv').load();
const express    = require('express');
const app        = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const apirouter = require('./apirouter');
const viewrouter = require('./viewrouter');

app.use('/api', apirouter);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use('/*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});


// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
});
```

But this way nothing is working.. It seems like every call is asking to the server and not looking into the public folder. So when i call for a .js file it load me a new index.html file... I don't know how to do.. Can you help me ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I was apparently doing wrong with :

Better use this :

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Than this :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```